# Lag on resize layout when soft keyboard gone

Tags: android-layout

In my app, I'm using view pager and on that view pager I have some form layout.

When I click on edit text to enter some text in form, soft keyboard comes up but the main layout takes much time to resize.

Same lagging issue occurs when soft keyboard goes.

Comment: Post some code. Is hard to tell without knowing what is happening on the resize.

Comment: Use whitespace and paragraphs to aid readability.

No need for thank you and name at end of question.